# Get the first percent from a list in bash

Tags: regex, sed

I have been trying to find a solution all day. I eventually came access a question here that provided two commands. They are:

```
echo blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35% | sed -e 's/[^%0-9 ]*//g;s/  */\n/g' | sed -n '/%/p'
echo blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35% | sed 's/.*[ \t][ \t]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

The first is supposed to give all the percentages found in the string and the second should only be used if you are expecting one percentage. My string will have more than one so I have been trying to use the first one. However, it returns all numbers in the strings and `n` representing spaces.

When I try to use the second command, I get the last percentage in my list which i don't need. I need the first percentage. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` would be easier to use as it supports non-greedy quantifier

```
$ echo 'blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35%' | perl -pe 's/.*?(\d+%).*/$1/'
20%
```

- `.*?` minimally match any character
- `(\d+%)` the first number followed by `%` combination
- `.*` rest of the line
- `$1` replace the line with text matched within `()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your regex defined, the `.*` always tends to be greedy by trying to match the longest available string. So the second attempt directly tries to match the sequence that is present at the last.

You can tweak your regex to below. Use an inverted match group to match anything that is not a sequence of digits followed by a `%` symbol, repeat that until a first pattern that *is* a sequence of digits followed by `%` occurs and print it

```
sed 's/^[^0-9%]*\([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

Remember using `awk` or `perl` is much more easier in cases like these. POSIX-ly `awk` regex match functions can do this as below. The `match()` functions scans  the leftmost substring matched by the regular expression

```
awk 'match($0, /([[:digit:]]*)%/){ print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1) }'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `grep` available, that's probably the easiest one for the job:

```
$ echo blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35% |
  grep -o "[0-9]\+ \?%"                   # at least one number, possibly a space and %
20%
35%
```

and if you need just the first one, pipe the previous to `head -1`:

```
$ echo blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35% |
  grep -o "[0-9]\+ \?%" |                 # at least one number, possibly a space and %
  head -1                                 # take the first
20%
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert spaces to new lines and grep for lines ending with %:

```
$ echo 'blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35%' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '%$'
20%
35%
```

- Fast
- POSIX
- Obvious

If you have embedded spaces, show an example of how you distinguish embedded from not for a more comprehensive (cough) solution.

If you're worried about false positives, insist on leading numerics compatible with your format: signed, whole, fractional, scientific etc. Chomp white space, etc.

By splitting, you bypass all the greedy shenanigans and can get down to the business of matching.